# What is the reason of putting "on" in this sentence?

Tags: usage

Some occupational therapists help kids create alternate ways to play popular games they might miss out **on** because of their illness or injury.

Answer (score 2):

This is the part that has most to do with "on"

> the popular games they might miss out on

Another way to say this would be:

> The kids that **missed out on playing popular games** are being helped by therapists... etc.

Hope this helps you understand.

Comment: A comma is not standard after games, because it separates the subject *kids* and the verb *are being helped.* The words between the subject and verb form a relative clause, which the mind processes as a clause, which offsets its relative length. In other words, this is both overuse and incorect use of the comma (,).

Answer (score 1):

"Miss out" is a phrasal transitive verb that means to fail to include somebody or something that should be included. When miss out is used in this sense, it doesn't need the preposition "on" such as he missed me out in the cricket team.

When miss out precedes the preposition "on" something, it means to fail to benefit from or take advantage of something useful. In this sense, the preposition "on" is a must; it cannot be omitted. Here it is an intransitive verb. The preposition on of this phrasal verb "miss out on something" has been used in the sentence in question at its natural and appropriate place. Some people may think that it should be written as "........popular games on which they might miss out because of their illness or injury", but I think this does not sound natural to native speakers.