# "Miss the opportunity" vs. "miss out on the opportunity"

Tags: difference, phrases

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between the phrase *miss the opportunity* and *miss out on the opportunity*? For example:

> I'd hate to **miss the opportunity** to go abroad next summer.
>
> I'd hate to **miss out on the opportunity** to go abroad next summer.

Comment: There is no definite difference. “Miss out” may be used to emphasize the sense of it being something done to the speaker rather than just happening but not necessarily.

Comment: 'Miss out on' is less formal, and was until recently mainly an Americanism.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Miss out on/miss out/miss](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/245212/miss-out-on-miss-out-miss). Also [What is the reason of putting “on” in this sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35414/what-is-the-reason-of-putting-on-in-this-sentence)

Comment: FumbleFingers: Not it doesn't. Thanks though

Comment: In the "phrasal verb" form, the preposition ***out*** evokes a ***container*** metaphor not present in the "base" form. What that implies is *You're on the outside - **excluded*** - from being ***in on*** some benefit that ***others*** are gaining but you're not. As opposed to you simply failing to get something that perhaps has no relevance to what anyone else gets.

Comment: That's to say *Don't miss X* is "neutral", and can cover a wide range of contexts where having / experiencing X is to your benefit. But *Don't miss **out** on X* strongly implies *Don't be **left out**. You should be **in the group** of people who benefit from X*.